# DisplayFormulaNumbered

Tags: notebooks, style

I'm using *Mathematica* 10.3 and have a question regarding the DisplayFormulaNumbered Style: is there a way to tell *Mathematica*

- to number the formulas not only 1,2,3... but 1.1, 1.2, 1.3
- when it has to begin with the next chapter (say 2.1, 2.2,...)

I have understood that this requires changing the style but I don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Since nobody else has taken a stab at this, I will, despite my limited knowledge of style sheets.  You will need two separate pieces: i. reset the counter when the chapter changes, and ii. change the `StyleData["DisplayFormulaNumbered"]`.

You can cause the counter to reset by changing the `CounterAssignments` for the `StyleData["Chapter"]`.  Here it is the last assignment:

```
CounterAssignments -> {{"Section", 0}, {"Definition",  0},{"DisplayFormulaNumbered", 0}}
```

You change the style data by adding to the `StyleDefinitions` of your notebook.  E.g., after completing step i., you might try adding,

```
Cell[StyleData["DisplayFormulaNumbered"],
 CounterIncrements -> "DisplayFormulaNumbered",
 CellFrameLabels -> {
   {Cell[
     TextData[{"(", CounterBox["Chapter"], ".", CounterBox["DisplayFormulaNumbered"], ")"}], 
     "DisplayFormulaNumberedLabel", 
     CellBaseline -> Baseline], Inherited
    }, 
    {Inherited, Inherited}
  }
 ]
```